# Why does 'await' change the thread context in WinForms program.cs

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

The normal behavior of using await to call an asynchronous method is that its context stays the same as shown in the example below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //main thread here
        await SampleAsync();
        //stays as main thread
        var g = 10;
    }

    static async Task SampleAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

But when I use this in the Winforms Main console method call, this behavior is no longer true: After calling the await method, the thread change from the main thread to the worker thread. Why is this? I would like for it to stay on the Main (UI Thread) after the await call.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        //Main Thread here
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        //Why does it turn in to worker thread here? ConfigureAwait(false) is not used here?!
        var g = 5;
        //Run other Application.Run() if certain conditions apply; but I need to be in the Main Thread.
    }
```

In case you are wondering what I am trying to achieve, I am trying to catch the errors in the async method, MainAsync, rather than Main so that I can avoid having to disentangle errors from the AggregateException (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/JJ991977.aspx; Figure4). I also want to stay in the UI thread so I can run other Application.Run in the UI thread.

Comment: Try moving the code into a button click event handler instead of form load. Also, see my own question about what happens when Application.Run or Form1.ShowDialog returns here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439669/hosting-net-and-winforms-synchronizationcontexts-is-reset-when-showdialog-of

Comment: Why did you make your MainAsync async anyway? It is synchronous by nature because it keeps the process alive.

Comment: The code working in the form1_load as working as expected, as the context remains the same. Not sure what moving the code to a button click event will achieve?

Comment: @usr In my real application, after "Form1" runs, I call an async method to do some work in MongoDb (The latest mongo c# driver db calls are async by nature and I have let it bubbled up). That is what the Task.Delay is supposed to represent.

Comment: @geohnH and you need to stay on the same thread? In that case set up a single threaded sync context that you control. Nito async has such a class. But why is your code thread-affine?

Comment: @usr I believe the reason to stay on the same thread is because he plans on doing a additional `Application.Run` later on in the program (see the last line of comments in the example) and would need to make sure that the thread that does that is a STA thread (which a threadpool thread from the default scheduler would not be)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain good guess, probably true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Application.Run` is what "Runs" the continuation on the main thread, once `Application.Run` returned `SynchronizationContext.Current` was unset for the "UI Thread" therefor the `await` had to use the default context which is the ThreadPool.

Because you have no UI at that point I would recommend doing a synchronous wait (`.Wait()`) instead of a `await` at that point, that will make sure you are still on the same STA thread for your later `Application.Run` calls.

**EDIT**: Did not see your mention about disentangling AggregateException, all await is doing with the AggregateException is doing the equivalent of

```
catch(AggregateException ex)
{
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
}
```

Which causes the first exception of the AggregateException to be re-raised without messing up it's stack trace.